# Is there a way to force a browser to not use a .swf file from cache? From within the .swf file itself?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So I have a .SWF file, there are several people I know calling the .SWF file directly from my server onto their page.

I need to do some maintenance on the .SWF and wanted to replace the current SWF file with one that just says "under maintenance". I know there are ways to do it via html/php but I do not have access to the html/php code the other people are using on their servers to call my .swf file.

I plan to name the .swf file with the same exact name, so it doesn't break for the other people linking to my .swf file from their website.. but my concern is that their users will show the a cached version of the .swf file instead of my new .swf file.

Is there actionscript or anything I can put in the .swf so that it prevents the users on the other site from using a cached version?

Thank you.

Comment: By definition no you can't do that.

Comment: editing the .htaccess to somehow cause all .swf files to not be cached is not possible right?

Comment: Everything is possible except from within the swf itself. It is the one being cached it cannot uncache itself magically.

Comment: If the .swf size is different but same name.. would the browser by default try to load it from cache or load the new .swf file with same name since it has a different size?

Comment: Just trying to figure out how to make sure anyone who accesses the .swf file gets the latest version... even if a 3rd party is linking directly to the .swf itself.

Comment: File size should have no effect on cache but eventually the cache will update itself at some point. If your swf is loaded as is from external parties then you'll have no control on how they handle the caching.

Comment: If you reply as an answer i'll accept your answer, unless someone comes up with a magical solution lol.

Comment: I gave you some info but it's hardly an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If people are loading the SWF file directly, the only thing you can do is replace it by a polite loader.

This new structure would be:

- a new SWF with the same new from the previous and rename the original one.
- this new "main" file would load the original one appending new Date().getTime() to the end of the file name.

  loader.load(new URLRequest('myOriginal.swf?k='+new Date().getTime()));

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the caching period for .swf files via an .htaccess rule.  For your purposes, reduce it to 1 hour or less.  That will force all the newly requested swf files to be redownloaded.

When you're finished with maintenance, remove the rule or increase the caching period.